# Using Sidekiq with Padrino - Sidekiq does not inherit the environment

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sidekiq, padrino

I am using Padrino (0.13.2) with Sidekiq (4.2.7) and I have some Mailers set up in Padrino to fire off when things occur in my app.

Here's the set up info (from [here](https://gist.github.com/passcod/3754086), mostly)

At first, when running sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq -r ./config/workers.rb` it wasn't getting any of my environment (Models, database, etc) so that was fairly useless.

Now I'm starting it with `bundle exec sidekiq ./config/boot.rb` so that it has access to the entire Padrino environment. No problem, everything works great.

HOWEVER, I'm trying to send a mailer and it doesn't work.

```
Portal::App.delay.deliver(:user, :confirm, "John Doe", "confirmation link here")
```

This gets scheduled into sidekiq no problem, but when it goes to run it, it again isn't getting the padrino environment because I receive the error: `WARN: RuntimeError: mailer 'user' is not registered`

I can run the mailer command from the Padrino console without a problem (it sends) but when I schedule it with sidekiq it fails. Help?

Oh, I should also add that in TESTS it works!!! WTF??